# Deleting row with html button

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-delete

I am creating an delete function.
However when I try to delete a row it deletes all my entry's.

```
if(@$_REQUEST['action']=="del")
{
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM rythm WHERE rythm_Name=".round($_REQUEST['id2']));
}
```

this part is inside my HTML

```
                echo "<td class=tabval><a onclick=\"return confirm
('are you sure?');\" href=index.php?action=del&id2=". $row['rythm_Name'].">
<span class=red>[test]</span></a></td>";

            } ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure not all of your entries has the same `rythm_Name` ?

Comment: why you use round on `$row['rythm_Name']`

Comment: it deletes not the row i select, but all rows. Resulting in an empty database

Comment: @PeterVandeLaar once again, are you sure that not all of your entries match the `$_REQUEST['id2']` value in `rythm_Name`

Comment: nope i receive different URL's, for example: http://localhost/school/index.php?action=del&id2=test

Comment: And what do you expect to recieve on `round(test)` ? :)

Comment: If it is a string, quote it, and do not use mathematical functions on it. What to round on a string?

Comment: i expect it to delete the item with rythm_Name: "test"

Comment: @PeterVandeLaar no it was not my question, what do you expect the output of `ROUND()` function to be with a parameter of type `STRING`

Comment: you've got a point :P any idea what function to use then?

Comment: No function? Just quote it. Ofcourse, it will be very unsafe at all. You should take a look how to escape strings (the deprecated lib mysql_ has a mysql_real_escape_string) or better, switch to new api (mysqli, pdo) and use prepared statements. Anyway, for first time, using single quotes around the string will help you achieve your goal.

Comment: solved it! thank you all very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the round of in `where` clause. Is there any reason to round of the `$_REQUEST['id']`.

If `$_REQUEST['id']` holds string value, You need surrounded with quotes.

Try this,

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM rythm WHERE rythm_Name='".$_REQUEST['id2']."'");
```

Comment: @PeterVandeLaar go back to the comments on the main post

Comment: @PeterVandeLaar : What values `$_REQUEST['id'] ` holds?

Comment: it holds text and numbers.

Comment: @PeterVandeLaar : I updated my answer now. check it.

Comment: @PeterVandeLaar : Numbers which is in `float` or `double` value?

Comment: Does not matter. If it holds texts, then quotation is obligatory. You can check earlier if it is double/float and use `round()`, afterwards put the new value which was rounded, in single quotes again

Comment: @PeterVandeLaar . Yeah. According to Royal Bg point, If it holds both strings and numbers, you need to check it before executing query. If the numbers are in `float` or `double` value, use `round of ` function.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
rythm_Name=".$_REQUEST['id2']);
```

remove round please.

Comment: And what it will change?